# How to copy SQL Server database from Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

We have an Access UI to Sql Server database. The user connects to many databases (containing the same tables with different data), can choose between them. We use this for versioning. We want to make him able to copy and delete databases right from Access UI. He should be able to copy at least to the same server, and ideally also to other server.

Comment: Do you want to copy data from the Access DB's to the SQL DB, or is this pure SQL DB's accessed from a Access UI. When you say copy DB's do you mean copy data, or the complete DB?

Comment: All data is in SQL DB, accesed via linked tables. I want to create new database as a copy of other one. Currently we do it with backup/restore of SSMS.

Comment: You might like to read http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/27/sql-server-copy-database-from-instance-to-another-instance-copy-paste-in-sql-server/ and http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/07/sql-server-2008-2008-r2-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-data-schema-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/  You should be able to run scripts from Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final solution:

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection

conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" dbServer & ";" _
    & "User ID=" & user & ";Password=" & password
conn.Open

' backup
conn.Execute "BACKUP DATABASE [" & sourceDb & "] TO  [backup device] WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10"

' restore
conn.Execute "RESTORE DATABASE [" & targetDb & "] FROM  [abcosting temporary backup] WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10, " & mdf_move & ", " & ldf_move
```

Answer (score 0):

A Backup and restore is probably going to be your best bet. There is another way as well. But there will be some restrictions.

You can detach the DB you want to copy, make a copy of the files attach the old one, and attach the new one as a new DB. Your problem will be because you are using Access to connect to the DB, you will not be able to detach it because there is a connection to it, and all connections must be dropped before you can detach it.

Dropping the DB (delete it) will have the same problem. It won't drop unless you there is no connections on the DB.